# How to view the battery usage settings in android?

Tags: android

I want to view battery usage setting through application settings->about phone->Battery use

How to view this through application please help me

Comment: Go to other questions now, and accept the top-most answer, to provide expected feedback to the SO community.

Answer (score 12):

To show power usage information to the user, you can start activity using **Intent.ACTION_POWER_USAGE_SUMMARY**

```
Intent intentBatteryUsage = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_POWER_USAGE_SUMMARY);        
    startActivity(intentBatteryUsage);
```

Comment: thanks for ur help.how to turn on turn off bluetooth using toogle button manualy in application

Comment: look into the Bluetooth adapter, you will find solution,visit this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html

Comment: thanks. how to get the state[ON or OFF] of automatic brightness in android

Comment: Is it also possible to go to a specific app battery stats?

Answer (score 1):

@Tamil, to turn on/off Bluetooth, first u have to make object("mBTadapter") of bluetoothAdapter class, then call

**mBTAdapter.enable();**

or

**mBTAdapter.disable();**

programetically,,

Answer (score 0):

settings->about phone->Battery use?
i don't know you mean.
you can not see the battery details in this way?