# How to programmatically open Power Settings activity in Android?

Tags: android

Trying to open power settings. I don't see it here...

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html

Comment: No, Phil. Ultimately, we removed the "Battery Settings" functionality from the application as we felt that any basically experienced Android user would be able to readily access the power settings, etc. from the stock OS UI path.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to open it using `Intent`. A quick search for the power settings activity has found the setting `com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider`. You should be able to open it from your `Activity` using the code:

```
startActivity(new Intent("com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider"));
```

Comment: That line of code crashes/force close. I've added the permission DEVICE_POWER.

Comment: Did adding said permission take care of the crash?

Comment: @Mr. Awesome, is this an activity that you are able to access from the main settings?

Comment: I should be able to, but I have a "Battery Settings" button and would like to jump directly to there via a click.

Comment: @Mr. Awesome, this is a duplicate question. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673036/create-battery-usage-intent-android

Comment: No, It's not a duplicate question, changing the actual battery settings and configuration is not equal to viewing the current battery usage.

Comment: This again doesn't point directly to a battery settings activity, but it may prove more useful than the other post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742592/how-to-view-the-battery-usage-settings-in-android